# Regex (lookbehind?)

Tags: regex

I need to turn this:

```
zz  zz zz   zzzzYzzzzXzzzz zz     zzzzzz                zzzz zzYzz
```

into this:

```
1Y1X1Y1
```

Preferably in one fell swoop.

`zz\s*zz` is good but you need to run it several times to achieve what I need.

Pair is the minimum unit of z.

zz is separated from each other by any number and combination of white spaces (tabs, spaces).

X and Y can be any strings except z and white spaces.

White spaces are always bordered by zz (and are inside Y and X strings).

It would be best if this would be in VBA-compatible syntax.

Comment: What is the context: Word or Excel?

Comment: a txt file, or rather one huge string that VBA need to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in GNU sed with

```
sed -r 's/[z ]+/1/g'
```

If that's not what you want,
edit your question to describe what you want more clearly.

Comment: I need this done in VBA or if not, then at least I'd like to be able to check it online (regexr.com). I checked you code online, it doesn't seem to work. Why is there only one z, when I have them in pairs?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code would look something like the code below:

```
Sub test()
MsgBox ReplaceIt("zz  zz zz   zzzzYzzzzXzzzz zz     zzzzzz                zzzz zzYzz")
End Sub

Function ReplaceIt(strIn As String) As String
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RE.Pattern = "[z ]+"
RE.Global = True
ReplaceIt = RE.Replace(strIn, "1")
End Function
```

Here is the result of this example as run in Word:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have disregarded two things. There are tabs there too, not just spaces and there are spaces inside Y and X strings (they should not be eliminated). This what seems to work:

' "[" & Chr(12) & "]*" & "\s*" & "[" & Chr(12) & "]+"'